# How to pass an array of parameters to the bind_param?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

i'm getting the folowing error:

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()
```

i believe it's because i'm assigning the parameters to the bind_param method the wrong way. The question is how to pass an array of parameters to the bind_param?

This is my function:

```
function read($sql, $params)
{
   $parameters = array();
   $results = array();

   // connect
   $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'db') or die('There was a problem connecting to the database. Please try again later.');

   // prepare
   $stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql) or die('Error preparing the query');

   // bind param ????????????
   call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);

   // execute
   $stmt->execute();

   // bind result
   $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

   while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {
      $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
   }

   call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

   // fetch
   while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
     $x = array();

     foreach( $row as $key => $val ) {
        $x[$key] = $val;
     }

     $results[] = $x;
  }

  return $results;
}
```

This is how i call it:

```
$params = array('i'=>$get_release, 'i'=>$status);
$result_set = read('SELECT release_id, release_group_id, status_id, name, subname, description, released_day, released_month, released_year, country_id, note, is_master_release, seo_url, meta_description, is_purchased FROM `release` WHERE release_id = ? AND status_id = ?', $params);
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute multiple query or try to bind many parameters to a single query?

Comment: im trying to bind many parameters to a single query. I though of using an associative array to pass the type and the value to bind_param

Comment: Any reason you're using MySQLi? I would think that PDO's discrete `PDOStatement::bindParam` would fit better

Comment: @Phil maybe for a future update i'll use pdo

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
$params = array('i'=>$get_release, 'i'=>$status);
```

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php):

> Note that when two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first.

You're passing an array with one element and your statement has two placeholders.

Comment: the array has 2 elements (placeholders), no? the type i for $get_release and type i for $status

Comment: @Marco - The syntax for `array()` is that the index (an integer or a string) goes to the left of `=>` and the value to the right. You're using the same index for both `$get_release` and `$status`. The second one clobbers the first, so your array is only one long. According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), for two placeholder positions, you should be passing three arguments to `bind_param`, so the array should be: `array('ii', $get_release, $status)`.

Comment: i didnt know you could pass all in one array like that

Comment: im not sure what to do next inside my function, once i declare the array that way

Comment: im getting this error: Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference

Comment: @Marco - See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336332/my-php-array-of-references-is-magically-becoming-an-array-of-values-why) for a solution. It's very close to what you're trying to do.