# Assigning an array of references

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I've not been able to find an explanation for this behavior.

For context, I'm working on dynamically binding parameters for prepared SQL statements using the `call_user_func_array` function.  I've created a simple function that takes an array and then returns an array of references to that array's values:

```
public function returnReferenceArray($array)
{
    foreach(array_keys($array) as $value)
    {
        $refs[] = &$array[$value];
    }

    return $refs;
}
```

This works just fine when calling it directly as a parameter of the `call_user_func_array` function, like so:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),  $obj->returnReferenceArray($bind_params));
```

The behavior is different, however, when assigning the returned array to a variable, like so:

```
$ref_params = $obj->returnReferenceArray($bind_params);

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"),  $ref_params);
```

I get this warning:

Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given

I don't necessarily have a problem to solve; I'm just trying to figure out why PHP treats the array of references this way when assigned versus returned.

---

**UPDATE WITH MORE RESEARCH**

To test this behavior more simply, I've run a couple of arrays through a series of tests to figure out in what scenarios references that are contained within an array are maintained, and it seems like using functions to insert references simply doesn't work.  Here's my simplified test:

```
function returnReferenceArray($array)
{
    foreach(array_keys($array) as $value)
    {
        $refs[] = &$array[$value];
    }

    return $refs;
}

function referenceReferenceArray($varray, &$rarray)
{
    foreach(array_keys($varray) as $value)
    {
        $rarray[] = &$varray[$value];
    }
}

$value_array = array(
    "foo" => 1,
);

$ref_array[] = &$value_array["foo"]; //reference is maintained

$ref_array = array();
$ref_array = returnReferenceArray($value_array); //reference is NOT maintained

$ref_array = array();
referenceReferenceArray($value_array, $ref_array); //reference is NOT maintained
```

Here's a gist with output to demonstrate the behavior:

https://gist.github.com/twistofreality/3b4760aba008f7620d10

All of that being said, there must be some sort of reference being maintained since calling my function as a parameter of `call_user_func_array` is valid for `bind_param`, but, given the results of my testing, I'm now really confused about the mechanics defining the behavior of arrays of references.

I'm hopeful that someone can point out something obvious that I'm overlooking.

---

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Looks like this is well-covered territory.  I did search for a while on SO before posting, but then I noticed this in the "related" section:

[My PHP array of references is "magically" becoming an array of values... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336332/my-php-array-of-references-is-magically-becoming-an-array-of-values-why)

Regardless, I'm still not sure why this works when I call the function directly as a parameter of `call_user_func_array` versus assigning the result of the function to another variable. It'd be great if anyone has any insight along those lines.

Comment: `call_user_func_array()` passes the argument array __by value__

Comment: pass by value is bad

Comment: possible duplicate of [My PHP array of references is "magically" becoming an array of values... why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336332/my-php-array-of-references-is-magically-becoming-an-array-of-values-why)

Comment: @Joseph8th yes, I think you're right. For whatever it's worth, I did find that I need to pass the original array to my function by reference itself (I updated the gist to reflect as much), which works just fine. So it seems like it's a PHP memory management quirk as the linked question suggests.

Comment: Although, I'm still not sure why this works when I call the function directly as a parameter of `call_user_func_array`. The inconsistent behavior in that regard makes me wonder if maybe this isn't _exactly_ duplicate.

Comment: PHP has many of these quirks. It's ad-hoc design lends itself to common use scenarios in web dev (particularly dynamic typing) but the same ad-hoc factor also gives it a well-deserved reputation for unpredictability.

Answer (score 1):

This is because PHP assignments create a copy. IOW, it's assignment by value. See the manual regarding [Assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Try

```
$ref_params = &$obj->returnReferenceArray($bind_params);
```

to get a reference to the array of references (I haven't tried this... so let us know if it works, please).

Comment: @Joshepth8th Unfortunately, this exhibits the same behavior. The issue seems to be with the references contained within the array itself; whether the array is a reference or not doesn't seem to matter in this scenario.  I've done some more testing that seems to indicate that references housed within arrays simply aren't maintained as references when assigned via function. I'll edit my original question with my findings.